# How to configure audio on a headless server

Tags: 14.04, server, sound, pulseaudio

I have a headless server that appears to have audio built into the motherboard which I need to configure.

I'm using `spd-say` to test it (also the reason I'm configuring audio). Currently, I don't get any audio output on any of the ports on the system.

I see what looks like two audio controllers:

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation C610/X99 series chipset HD Audio Controller (rev 05)
05:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
06:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Following some other articles, I've listed the sinks using `pacmd`. I'm not familiar with this tool though. The output below looks somewhat different than on my laptop.

```
$ pacmd list-sinks
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> 1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 1000
    volume: 0:  90% 1:  90%
            0: -2.75 dB 1: -2.75 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.21 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 4
    linked by: 4
    configured latency: 0.50 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 11
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

I don't know what devices I should be expecting to look for in /dev.

It's also not clear if there is an option in `spd-say` that I need to set to specify the output device.

Everything in the sound troubleshooting wiki seems to check out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Comment: I can't remember the exact answer but when I configured a headless test setup for sound I sometimes had to enable permissions to access the audio group for that user - though according to [the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/TheAudioGroup) this is a bad idea :). What program(s) to you want to receive audio from?

Comment: I'm trying to get the command line speech synthesizer `spd-say` to work. I'll retry everything with sudo.

Comment: Ah, yes, `sudo aplay asoundfile.wav` does work. Now to figure out how to get that to work without sudo. Adding the user to the audio group hasn't worked so far.

Comment: @Wilf your comment was correct, it was a permission issue. I've opened another question for an issue with `spd-say`, but after adding the audio group to my user I can run `aplay` successfully. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it, and thank you for the help!

Comment: Try `alsamixer` and see if the volume levels are shown, try setting the levels to a higher volume, then exit alsamixer, after which you can play something and expect some audio output. Place a screenshot in your question so we can see what's installed and working in alsamixer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a workaround to this issue is to add the user(s) to the `audio` group  so they can access the audio outputs. This may have limitations such as you may still need a audio program to interface with ALSA, which when you are logged in a desktop environment is normally done via a `pulseaudio` server or similar.

Note this is [not recommended on the wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/TheAudioGroup). This may just be as it will then override other users and programs but it might be due to security implications as well.